# Inheritance, polymorfism, interfaces, Java coding excercises

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I'm pretty new in this world and, I'm learning how to make codes by trying to do exercises that a friend sent me but I have a problem and I don't know exactly what it is.

The topic is inheritance, polymorphism, and interfaces

I am supposed to have these 3 animals and give them food (fish, meat, garbage) and they will answer if they like it or not.

This is my "Gato" subclass

```
package Animal; public class Gato implements Animal {

String nombre;


public Gato() {

    this.nombre = "Missi";
}

public Gato(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

@Override
public String hablar() {
    return "Miauuuuu";
}

@Override
public String giveFood(String food) {       
    if(alimento.equals("fish")) { 
    return "ñam ñam"; }else{ 
    return "i dont like it"; 

    }

} 

public String toString(){ return "Soy un Gato y me llaman "+ nombre; }

}
```

This is my interface

```
package Animal; public interface Animal {
String DEFINICION = "Ser orgánico que vive, siente y se mueve por propio impulso";

public String hablar();

public String giveFood(String alimento); }
```

And this is my main

```
Public class Main {
static Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in).useLocale (Locale.US);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int operacion;
        boolean salir = false;
        // CREAR OBJETOS
        Gato gat = new Gato();
        Perro per = new Perro();
        Tigre tig = new Tigre();

        while (!salir) {

            System.out.println("\nElige el tipo de animal: ");
            System.out.println(" 1 - Perro / 2 - Gato / 3 - Tigre " + " / 4 - Salir");
            // Permite capturar lo que se escribe por teclado y lo deja en la
            // variable operación.

            operacion = entrada.nextInt();

            switch (operacion) {

            case 1:
                System.out.println(per.toString());
                System.out.println(per.hablar());
                System.out.println(giveFood(per));
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println(gat.toString());
                System.out.println(gat.hablar());
                System.out.println(giveFood(gat));
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println(tig.toString());
                System.out.println(tig.hablar());
                System.out.println(giveFood(tig));
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("Bye bye");

                salir = true;

                break;

            default:

                System.out.println("Seleccione otra operación");

            }
        }
    }

    public static String darDeComer(Animal ani) {

        boolean salir = false;
        while (!salir) {

            System.out.println("What do we give them? ");
            System.out.println(" 1 - fish / 2 - meat / 3 - garbage " + " / 4 - Salir");
            int comida = entrada.nextInt();

            switch (comida) {

            case 1: 
                System.out.println(giveFood(ani));      

                break;

            case 2:                 
                break;

            case 3: 
                                break;
            case 4:
                salir = true;

                break;
            }

            return "";
        }

    }
}
```

So how do I proceed? I can't get the answer from my subclasses, and I don't know how to give the "animals" specific "food" to gain and specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to avoid writing the exact code because you are close and it will be better to work it out yourself...

giveFood() is a method that belongs to each animal, just like toString() and hablar(). So you need to call it in each case, just like the other two functions.

At the beginning of your program, after you prompt for animal type, you should next prompt "What type of food would you like to give?" (use nextLine() for that input instead of nextInt()). Save that input in a string variable called: "food".

Then under each case you print out the result of giveFood(), passing in the food variable:

```
System.out.println(gat.giveFood(food));
```

For "gato" type, you'd expect that if you type "fish" when prompted for food, he will reply with "nom nom". If you reply with anything else he will say: "i don't like it".

You could stop reading at this point and just get your code working as described above, but then you may wish to go a little further since you are trying to learn. The way the 3 cases are setup above, it's not really taking advantage of the inheritance/polymorphism.

The point of polymorphism is that you can have objects with different "guts under the hood" but treat them the same on the outside because the public interface to them is identical. To better illustrate that, you want your code to create a *single animal object variable*. Your case statement would then just initialize the variable to one of the three types. Then after the case, you can call the three methods on the object and the output will be different based on the type:

```
Animal someAnimal;

switch (operacion) {
    case 1:
        someAnimal = new Perro();
        break;
    case 2:
        someAnimal = new Gato();
        break;
    case 3:
        someAnimal = new Tigre();
        break;
}

System.out.println(someAnimal.toString());
System.out.println(someAnimal.hablar());
System.out.println(someAnimal.giveFood(food));
```

Comment: @model_dialog I´m really grateful for the advice, i moved another step towards completing the excersice. Thank you so much!